# Prove that $I = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0, \frac{n + 2}{n + 1}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> In the Euclidean metric space R, the subset
> $$
> I = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(0, \frac{n + 2}{n + 1}\right)
>   \subseteq \mathbb{R}
> $$ is not open.
> Compute I and prove this fact.

Can someone start listing the elements of $I$? I'm having trouble figuring them out.

Comment: @psidaga No. $I$ is the intersection of these sets, not the sets containing them.

Comment: Compute the value explicitly, $I=(0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :** For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$\frac{n+2}{n+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{n+1}$$